# how to get data from splunk dashboard to simple Html Front page (with Angular)?

Tags: angular, splunk

Hi I'm new with Splunk so sorry on the strange question

I have dashboard with info and I want create (for example)

```
<div></div>
```

if I have 20 elements in the dashboard, this div will duplicated (with the info).

Thank you all about the help!
I need it.

Comment: what have you tried? Can you show us any effort from your side?

Comment: This is my Dashboard http://imgur.com/a/9Rou9, And I want (like ng-reapet -> Angular) create my divs